# Volume group not found

Tags: 16.04, server, lvm

I'm pretty new at this and I'm having trouble with my volume group when I try to `vgextend`. I get `Volume Group "R2D2-vg" not found` when I know the volume group exists.

My volume groups:

```
$ sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               R2D2-vg
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        1
Metadata Sequence No  3
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                2
Open LV               2
Max PV                0
Cur PV                1
Act PV                1
VG Size               3.64 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              953611
Alloc PE / Size       953611 / 3.64 TiB
Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
VG UUID               [SOME_UUID]
```

My physical volumes:

```
$ sudo pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sda3
VG Name               R2D2-vg
PV Size               3.64 TiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
Allocatable           yes (but full)
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              953611
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          953611
PV UUID               [SOME_UUID]

"/dev/sdb1" is a new physical volume of "3.64 TiB"
--- NEW Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdb1
VG Name
PV Size               3.64 TiB
Allocatable           NO
PE Size               0
Total PE              0
Free PE               0
Allocated PE          0
PV UUID               [SOME_UUID]
```

The command that fails:

```
$ sudo vgextend R2D2-vg /dev/sdb1
Volume group "R2D2-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group R2D2-vg
```

Why is the volume group not found? What have I missed?

Let me know if there's any other information/output you'd like.

Comment: It might be that  the name of the vg ends in some invisible character (e.g one or more blanks). You might find out by listing `/dev/mapper`, using `ls -b`.  If this is the case, you can rename the vg using the UUID with `vgrename`.

Comment: @ridgy You're my hero. Invisible characters FTW. Feel free to add an official answer and I'll accept it.